# How do I Split Huge File into Chunks of equal size in bash

Tags: linux, bash, bigdata, chunks

I have a huge file of 4GB of data i.e 523 rows & 2,655,566 columns. I would like to read the whole file in equally divided chunks. How to do so, suggest the best approach

Here I have 522 lines only and 2,655,566 columns. Which is the best way split by lines or M bytes etc

Comment: [split](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html)

Comment: Can you please help me with the bash command which divides the whole big file into equal chunks for example 10,000 each

Comment: Please read the manual and try to work out what options you need - you do need to put in some effort to solve your own problem. If you then have a specific problem describe what you ran and what problem you encountered. But this is not really a programming question and thus off-topic for Stack Overflow. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: okay, new to StackOverflow. Got it I'll do that

Comment: splitting by 10 000 CSV columns? For an **unquoted** CSV you could use `cut -d ',' -f 1-10000; cut -d ',' -f 10001-20000; ...` or better, with an `awk` program. If the CSV is quoted then you won't be able to use any standard tool

Comment: Try the `split` command.

Comment: What's the point in spliting it? What are you trying to achieve.  4

Answer (score 0):

May be try using

```
split –-verbose file_name
```

if you manually specify the each split size like

```
split -b100M file_name
```

where 100M for MB, similarly you can give K,M,G,T,PE